# How to calculate quartiles using schema and tables in Amazon Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I want to calculate first quartile, median, third quartile and 99th percentile in an Amazon Athena where database and tables are created from Glue Data Catalog.

The sample query I entered is:

```
select
  percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by duration column_name) as percentile_25,
  percentile_cont(0.50) within group (order by duration column_name) as percentile_50,
  percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by duration column_name) as percentile_75,
  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by duration column_name) as percentile_95
from "schema"."table_name";
```

What could be any other way to calculate the quartiles?

Comment: Athena does not use neither MySQL nor Postrges engines. Please provide sample data and desired output.

Comment: Does the provided query work for you? Or what the problem is?

Comment: The above query didn't work for me. I want to calculate the q1, median, q3 and 99th percentile for a specific column of a table using amazon athena query editor

Comment: How exactly it didn't work for you? Exception? Incorrect results?

Comment: "mismatched input '('. Expecting: 'BY'" I have tried by putting BY after group also but then again it didn't work. I have tried other methods too but not showing the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Athena is based on Trino/Presto which does not have `percentile_cont` function and `within group` syntax (seems you are trying to port SQL Server query). For Athena you can try using [`approx_percentile`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_percentile) aggregate function (can be used as window one but it seems that in your case you need `group by`). Something along these lines:

```sql
select approx_percentile(column_name, 0.25) percentile_25  
from "schema"."table_name"
group by some_id; -- or group by true
```

Window function can look like:

```sql
select approx_percentile(column_name, 0.25) over (partition by some_id order by duration) percentile_25  
    -- or
    -- approx_percentile(column_name, 0.25) over (order by duration) percentile_25 
from "schema"."table_name"
group by some_id;
```